# adding list of stream to bloc flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

Hello i am trying to get data from firestore map it to a stream i am using Rxdart how do i add this Stream of list of product to the stream.When i tried to do it it keeps saying.The argument type Stream> can't be assigned to parameter type List.I am new to flutter please help.

Product Service;

```
class ProductService {
  Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  var random = Random();

  Stream<List<Product>> fetchProducts() {
    return _db.collection('products').snapshots().map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
              .map((document) => Product.fromFirestore(document.data))
              .toList(),
        );
  }
}
```

bloc

```
class ProductBloc {
  final _products = BehaviorSubject<List<Product>>();
  final ProductService _db = ProductService();

//getters
  Stream<List<Product>> get products => _products.stream;
  Function(List<Product>) get changeProducts => _products.sink.add;

  loadData() async {
    try {
      var products = _db.fetchProducts();
      _products.sink.add(products);
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }

  dispose() {
    _products.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: fetchProducts() returns a Stream<List<Product>> and_products is a BehaviorSubject<List<Product>>(), it means it receives (with the add method) a List<Product>. You're basically feeding a stream with another stream, not what it's inside of the stream

Comment: ok thanks How do i map it to the behavior subject?i am already changed to a list?

Comment: _products.sink.addStream(products); that method consume the event of the stream products